# Using firebase as a Web client for a login system in app & when tested it I add username & password for a user and when I pressed login erver error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
 var ROOT_URL = "https://exampleapp.firebaseio.com/";   // Change to your Firebase App 
 var FIREBASE_CREDENTIAL = "yourAppSecret";             // Change to your Firebase App Secret 
 var firebase = { 
    register : function (email, password, callback) { 
        var emailReplace = email.replace(/\./g, ",");
        var beginRegister = function () { 
            requestObj = { "email" : email, "password" : password };
            var requestJSON = JSON.stringify(requestObj);
            var wcRegister = new SMF.Net.WebClient(
            { URL : ROOT_URL + "Users/" + emailReplace + ".json?auth=" + FIREBASE_CREDENTIAL, 
                httpMethod : "POST", 
                requestHeaders : ['Content-Type:application/json', 'X-HTTP-Method-Override:PATCH'], 
                requestBody : requestJSON, 
                onSyndicationSuccess : function (e) { 
                    //Registered, do something callback();
                }, onServerError : function (e) { 
                    //Do something 
                } 
            });

             wcRegister.run(true);
        };

        var isTaken = new SMF.Net.WebClient({ URL : ROOT_URL + "Users/" + emailReplace + ".json?auth=" + FIREBASE_CREDENTIAL, 
            httpMethod : "GET", 
            requestHeaders : ["Content-Type:application/json"], 
            onSyndicationSuccess : function (e) { 
                var response = JSON.parse(isTaken.responseText);
                if (response !== null) { 
                    //Email is taken, do something 
                } else { 
                    beginRegister();
                    //Email is not taken, continue 
                }
            }, 
            onServerError : function (e) { 
                //Server Error, do something 
            }
        });

        isTaken.run(true);
    }, 

    login : function (email, password, callback) { 
        var emailReplace = email.replace(/\./g, "%2C");
        var wcLogin = new SMF.Net.WebClient({ URL : ROOT_URL + "Users/" + emailReplace + ".json?auth=" + FIREBASE_CREDENTIAL, 
            httpMethod : "GET", 
            requestHeaders : ["Content-Type:application/json"], 
            onSyndicationSuccess : function (e) { 
                var responseText = JSON.parse(wcLogin.responseText);
                if (responseText) { 
                    if (password === responseText.password) { 
                        //User logged, do something 
                        callback();
                    } else { 
                        //Password is wrong, do something 
                    }
                } else { 
                    //User doesn't exist, do something 
                } 
            }, 
            onServerError : function (e) { 
                //Server error, do something 
            } 
        });
        wcLogin.run(true);
    }
}
```

This is the code I used to create a Web client and the software I am using is Smartface App Studio. Using firebase as a Web client for a login system in app & when tested it I add username & password for a user and when I pressed login it said server error.Thank you☺

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid pure code debugging/change requests don't work well on Stack Overflow - you should provide more specific detail on what goes wrong (in case of a server error, there is usually an error log available that gives more detailed info), and format the code properly (it's all in one huge line at the moment).

Comment: Please add enters and indentation to the code in your question. Right now it's almost impossible to read is and thus help you.

Comment: @CatherineLagoon If you're looking for people to debug your code you should probably put it in something like a codepen so that they can easily work on it -- questions where it seems like the person posting it hasn't event attempted to resolve it via simple debugging make people not want to help, have you tried throwing some console.logs in there? how far through did the system get? did it even call the login function? all valid questions

Comment: I don't need code debugging I've already done that I was asking as to how to solve the problem of their being a server error when signing in on the app. The code shows how I used firebase as a webclient just in case the server error happening was because of an error of how the client was created.